# Add Cookie keyword does not set the cookie as expected

Tags: firefox, cookies, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am running a robot test using the Add Cookie keyword. In Firefox if I click View Page Info -> Security -> Cookies the cookie value is set. However if I type in the console: document.cookie.split('; ') I don't see my cookie in the list.

Could anyone explain why that happens?

I am using Firefox 23.0.

Comment: Is it somehow related to persistent/session cookie types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a side-effect of using private browsing. The default profile used by Selenium2Library has private browsing enabled. Use the `ff_profile_dir` argument to `Open Browser` to point to a Firefox profile that does not have private browsing enabled.

From what I gather, it is a bug/quirk in Firefox. Both the Cookies dialog you mention and Selenium seem point to a cookie manager that is disconnected from the browser and the browser is using a different cookie manager to support private browsing.

See https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library/issues/177